# Copy folder from inside node js project directory to specified directory

Tags: node.js

So, I'm building my own node js module. My own node js module will be installed globally and I want it to be able to copy folders or files from inside its directory to a specified folder. How can I achieve this?

I've tried with `fs-extra` and `fs`, but it returned errors:

[image]

btw, these are the directories that I want to copy:

[image: directories]

Comment: show what you have done

Comment: The `cwd` in last exec seems wrong, shouldn't it be same as destination directory ?

Comment: @S.D. sorry but the `cwd` in the last exec isn't the concern